# Rails is only refreshing pages after a submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I have a rails app with foundation. It is not firing the foundation jquery on every page. I have the correct foundation code in application.js:
//= require foundation

```
$(function(){
   $(document).foundation(); 
});
```

If I refresh a page manually, it fires. If I just render the page using a link in the application, it does not fire.

I am using turbolinks in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

When using turbolinks, you will need to replace that javascript you have with this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

NOTE: For older versions of turbolinks, use `page:load` instead of `turbolinks:load`